# need help to model turbo compressor housing

Tags: modeling

[image: turbo compressor housing]

tried torus but I'm unable to achieve these fused results and just how to make it small as it goes down?

Comment: start from a cylinder, you add a bend modifier, and a curve to which the cylinder is bound by using `ctrl+p >> follow-curve`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it added a lost basic knowledge into my skill

Answer (score 4):

Enable the add extra curves addon.

[image]

Then add a curve->Spirals->Archemedian

[image]

Give the spiral some height

[image]

In the geometry section. give it some bevel depth

[image]

Then you can edit the radius of one of the end segments to make is smaller

[image]

For further editing convert from curve to mesh

[image]

Comment: thank you very much